# How to add modify this code to priotitize dim line's distance away from the object?

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

The code calculates the distance only to objects the dim lines are directly attached to. I wanted it to somehow base the distance for things such as holes inside an object to 200mm away (in a 1:10 scale) from the object than the 200m away from the hole directly. Somehow making the intersection of the dim line and the object to be basis for objects that are inside the object.

```
(defun c:DLA ( / sel ent txp al ar mp uALR s txpp uvt tp exss exssent exssl exssindex)

(defun deg2rad (ang / )
  (/ (* PI ang) 180.0)
)

(defun rad2deg ( ang / )
  (/ (* 180.0 ang) PI)
)

;; midpoint of 2 given points
(defun mid ( pt1 pt2 / )
  (mapcar '(lambda (x y) (+ (* 0.5 x) (* 0.5 y)))
  pt1
  pt2
  )
)

;;;  Calculate unit vector of vector a 
(defun uvec 
  (a / d)
  (setq d (distance '(0 0 0) a)
    a (mapcar '/ a (list d d d))
  )
)

; Compute the dot product of 2 vectors a and b
(defun dot ( a b / dd)
  (setq dd (mapcar '* a b))
  (setq dd (+ (nth 0 dd) (nth 1 dd) (nth 2 dd)))
)                   ;end of dot  

  (princ "\nInput Desired Distance: ")
  (setq dist (getreal))
  
  (princ "\nSelect Dimension(s) To Change: ")  
  
    (setq exss (ssget '((0 . "*dim*"))))                           
    (setq exssl (sslength exss))                                   
    (setq exssindex 0) 
    
    (repeat exssl                                                    
        (setq exssent (entget (ssname exss exssindex)))              

         (setq ent (cdr (car exssent)))                                 
         (setq txp (cdr (assoc 10 (entget ent))))
         (setq al (cdr (assoc 13 (entget ent))))
         (setq ar (cdr (assoc 14 (entget ent))))

         (setq mp (mapcar '/
                     (mapcar '+ al ar)
             '(2. 2. 2.)
             )
         )

        ; uALR = unit vector from al to ar
        (setq uALR (uvec (mapcar '- ar al)))
        (setq s (dot uALR (mapcar '- txp al)))
        
        ; txpp = projection of txp onto the line    
        (setq txpp
               (mapcar '+ al (mapcar '* uALR (list s s s)))
        )
        
        (setq uvt (uvec (mapcar '- txp txpp)))
        (setq tp (mapcar '+ mp (mapcar '* uvt (list dist dist dist))))
        
        (entmod
          (subst (cons 10 tp) (assoc 10 (entget ent)) (entget ent))
        )
        
        (entmod
          (subst (cons 11 tp) (assoc 11 (entget ent)) (entget ent))
        )

         
         (setq exssindex (+ exssindex 1))     
    )
    
(princ)

)
```

[image: Ref]